# How to access List variable from _Layout on View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have "list" variable on "_Layout" page in MVC.

```
List<object> list = object.GetList();
```

I've rendered my view say "Index" on _Layout page as :

```
@RenderBody()
```

How can I access "list" variable from "_Layout" page on "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method, without having to override anything, is if you are using `_ViewStart.cshtml`. Then you can add the property you want to access to `PageData`. This will then be available to your views that use that layout:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    PageData["PropertyFromLayout"] = new List<string>() { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
}
```

Then in your `view` you can access it like so:

```
@foreach (var item in PageData["PropertyFromLayout"])
    {
        @item;<br />
    }
```